# Не открывать окна поверх всего

Tags: ubuntu

Часто возникает ситуация, когда тыкаю, допустим, по иконке ide и пока она грузиться (несколько минут) я занимаюсь чем-то ещё. И всегда, даже если текущее окно активно, новое окно открывается поверх всех остальных, меня иногда пугают эти скримеры)

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли сделать так, чтобы только что открытые окна приложений не сменяли фокус с текущего окна на себя?

Comment: Попробуйте запускать с `&`

Comment: @dIm0n  ОП про *focus stealing,* вроде.

Comment: Извиняюсь за офтоп, но по-моему это ненормально если IDE грузится несколько минут. У меня на очень старом железе vscode грузится не дольше 10-20 секунд первый раз за день и секунд за 5 из кеша. Причём я считаю что это очень долго и часто пользуюсь редактором попроще (textadept), который всегда запускается мгновенно. Попробуйте отключить лишний функционал. Многие IDE из коробки имеют кучу встроенных плагинов, которые нужны далеко не каждому пользователю.

Comment: Советую добавить тег `gnome`, он ближе к вашему вопросу. `ubuntu` – более обширная тема.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите настройки используемого менеджера окон, там найдите: Prevent focus stealing.